# XPath - trim and starts-with together (cut of whitespaces)

Tags: xml, xpath, whitespace, trim

I have XML like this:

```
<div class="errorMessage">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="...">
                ABC - efg
            </a>
            <a href="...">
                HIJ - klm
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I select link's text which starts with "ABC"?
I need to trim the "text()" of "a" and apply "starts-with()" on it.
I have something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
//div[@class='errorMessage']/.//a[starts-with(normalize-space(./text())),'ABC')]/text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work:

`//div[@class='errorMessage']//a[starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'ABC')]/text()`